# How to scheduling multiple task through cron expression using Springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

I want to schedules multiple task using **@schedule** annotation using cron expression. I have three job which require to execute at fixed time. For example,Job-1 has been schedule every day at 11:PM, Job-2 has been scheduled every day 7AM-9PM in 1 hour interval and Job-3 has been schedule in every 1 hour. All the 3 schedule tasks are part of the same application.

I have tried the same but all three scheduling is not happening. My application is **SpringBoot application**.I am not new scheduling.Kindly help me out. Below is he my approach

**application.properties**

```
cron.expression.job1=0 0 23 * * ?
cron.expression.job2=0 0 7,9 * * ?
cron.expression.job3=0 0/60 * * ?
```

**Java Code**

```
 @EnableScheduling
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class Scheduler{
     // doCallScheduleJob Code
 }

class ScheduleJob{

  @Scheduled(cron="${cron.expression.job1}")
  public sycName1(){
           ///doSomething()     
  }

  @Scheduled(cron="${cron.expression.job2}")
  public sycName2(){
           ///doSomething()     
  }

  @Scheduled(cron="${cron.expression.job3}")
  public sycName3(){
           ///doSomething()     
  }
```

Comment: "I have tried the same but all three scheduling is not happening". You must include what you have tried, in the question, for others to help you.

Comment: @RamanujanR I have edited my queries with my approach...can you please look into this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure your TaskScheduler thread pool size. if you are not configure, the default size is 1 which is mean spring will execute your task one by one. You can configure your TaskScheduler below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringBootConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Executor getTaskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain bit more as I have edited my queries. I wanted to know, Whether I need to invoke the each task with each Thread explicitly or Springboot will take care of this

Comment: Please include the code as @AaricChen suggested. No need to invoke each task. Spring will do the rest. Also check `@Scheduled` methods are under package scanning. Also you are using `@Schedule` in two methods; is that a typo? Try all this, and comment the result. I've not tried Spring Boot yet, so cant comment on getting from property file using `$`. Better hard code it first.